# Need help to convert a XML file from Visual Tom into CSV files using AWK

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I would want to convert a XML file from Visual TOM in several CSV file

- a CSV file for the application with the properties (application name;retained value;comment value;frequency value;onDemand value;isAsked value ...)
- a CSV file for the application/job with the properties (application name;job name;retained value;comment value;information value;frequency value;onDemand value;isAsked value;cycleEnabled value ...)
- a CSV file for the scripts of the application/job (application name;job name;script value)
- a CSV file for the parameters of the application/job (application name;job name;parameter value)
- a CSV file for the ExpectedResource of the application/job with the properties and the value of ExpectedResource (application name;job name;resource name value;operator operator;wait value;startAfter value;free value; ressource value)
- a CSV file for the Node of the application/job with the properties of the Node (application name;job name;x value;y value;z value)
- a CSV file for the Node of the application with the properties of the Node (application name;x value;y value;z value)

we can have several parameters and ExpectedResource for a job

All the application do not necessarily have the same properties
All the job do not necessarily have the same properties
For example, you can find information value for the job name T_MIQ1 but not for job name T_SQL1

Do you know if is it possible in AWK in Redhat 7.9 ?

sorry for my bad english ...

**You will find here a extract of XML file from Visual TOM** :

```
    <Application name="A_MIQUADO_ENV" retained="0" comment="Execution Miquado" frequency="D" onDemand="0" isAsked="0" cycleEnabled="0" cycle="00:00:00" minStart="00:00:00" maxStart="23:59:59" mode="J" status="U" substatus="0" descOnErr="0" hostsGroup="RH-PD-hra-env" user="hraadmin" mepType="E">
      <Planning planning="1" formula="0" daysInWeek="NNNNNWN" daysInMonth="BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB" weeksInMonth="11111" monthsInYear="111111111111"/>
      <Jobs>
        <Job name="T_MIQ2" retained="0" comment="suivi marqueurs en vigueur" information="Attente lien obligatoire vers T_SQL2 actuellement NON-PLANIFIE" frequency="D" onDemand="0" isAsked="0" cycleEnabled="0" cycle="00:00:00" minStart="00:00:00" maxStart="23:59:59" mode="S" retcode="-1" status="U" statusTime="24-04-2023 04:02:33" substatus="0" appInErr="1" descOnErr="0" blockDate="0" restartType="M" restartCount="0" restartMax="1" restartDelay="00:00:00" restartLabel="0" timeBegin="1682214471" timeEnd="1682214472" ipid="0" mepType="E">
          <Script><![CDATA[#/exploit/scripts/vtom/vtom_start_job.ksh]]></Script>
          <Parameters>
            <Parameter><![CDATA[{RH_RT_PD_POARJ2}]]></Parameter>
            <Parameter><![CDATA[ENVMIQ{RH_RT_PD_MATENV}]]></Parameter>
          </Parameters>
          <ExpectedResources>
            <ExpectedResource resource="RH_RW_PD_hra1" operator="!" wait="1" startAfter="0" free="1">
              <Value><![CDATA[1]]></Value>
            </ExpectedResource>
          </ExpectedResources>
          <Node objectType="job" x="20" y="350" z="0"/>
        </Job>
        <Job name="T_SQL2" retained="0" comment="Exécution fichier SQL2" information="Attente lien facultatif vers T_MIQ1 actuellement NON-PLANIFIE" frequency="D" onDemand="0" isAsked="0" cycleEnabled="0" cycle="00:00:00" minStart="00:00:00" maxStart="23:59:59" mode="S" retcode="-1" status="U" statusTime="24-04-2023 04:02:33" substatus="0" appInErr="1" descOnErr="0" blockDate="0" restartType="M" restartCount="0" restartMax="1" restartDelay="00:00:00" restartLabel="0" timeBegin="1682214471" timeEnd="1682214471" ipid="0" mepType="E">
          <Script><![CDATA[#/exploit/scripts/vtom/vtom_start_job.ksh]]></Script>
          <Parameters>
            <Parameter><![CDATA[/exploit/hra/scripts/hraccess_miquado_sql2.ksh ENV $(date +%Y-%m-%d)]]></Parameter>
          </Parameters>
          <ExpectedResources>
            <ExpectedResource resource="RH_RW_PD_hra1" operator="!" wait="1" startAfter="0" free="1">
              <Value><![CDATA[1]]></Value>
            </ExpectedResource>
          </ExpectedResources>
          <Node objectType="job" x="20" y="240" z="0"/>
        </Job>
        <Job name="T_SQL3" retained="0" comment="Exécution fichier SQL3" information="Attente lien facultatif vers T_MIQ2 actuellement NON-PLANIFIE" frequency="D" onDemand="0" isAsked="0" cycleEnabled="0" cycle="00:00:00" minStart="00:00:00" maxStart="23:59:59" mode="S" retcode="-1" status="U" statusTime="24-04-2023 04:02:33" substatus="0" appInErr="0" descOnErr="0" blockDate="0" restartType="M" restartCount="0" restartMax="1" restartDelay="00:00:00" restartLabel="0" timeBegin="1682214472" timeEnd="1682214472" ipid="0" mepType="E">
          <Script><![CDATA[#/exploit/scripts/vtom/vtom_start_job.ksh]]></Script>
          <Parameters>
            <Parameter><![CDATA[/exploit/hra/scripts/hraccess_miquado_sql3.ksh ENV $(date +%Y-%m-%d)]]></Parameter>
          </Parameters>
          <ExpectedResources>
            <ExpectedResource resource="RH_RW_PD_hra1" operator="!" wait="1" startAfter="0" free="1">
              <Value><![CDATA[1]]></Value>
            </ExpectedResource>
          </ExpectedResources>
          <Node objectType="job" x="20" y="460" z="0"/>
        </Job>
        <Job name="T_MIQ1" retained="0" comment="suivi marqueurs sur tout l'historique" information="Attente lien obligatoire vers T_SQL1 actuellement NON-PLANIFIE" frequency="D" onDemand="0" isAsked="0" cycleEnabled="0" cycle="00:00:00" minStart="00:00:00" maxStart="23:59:59" mode="S" retcode="-1" status="U" statusTime="24-04-2023 04:02:33" substatus="0" appInErr="1" descOnErr="0" blockDate="0" restartType="M" restartCount="0" restartMax="1" restartDelay="00:00:00" restartLabel="0" timeBegin="1682214471" timeEnd="1682214471" ipid="0" mepType="E">
          <Script><![CDATA[#/exploit/scripts/vtom/vtom_start_job.ksh]]></Script>
          <Parameters>
            <Parameter><![CDATA[{RH_RT_PD_POARJ2}]]></Parameter>
            <Parameter><![CDATA[ENVMIQ{RH_RT_PD_MATENV}]]></Parameter>
          </Parameters>
          <ExpectedResources>
            <ExpectedResource resource="RH_RW_PD_hra1" operator="!" wait="1" startAfter="0" free="1">
              <Value><![CDATA[1]]></Value>
            </ExpectedResource>
          </ExpectedResources>
          <Node objectType="job" x="20" y="130" z="0"/>
        </Job>
        <Job name="T_SQL1" retained="0" comment="purge de ZYO3" frequency="D" onDemand="0" isAsked="0" cycleEnabled="0" cycle="00:00:00" minStart="00:00:00" maxStart="23:59:59" mode="S" retcode="-1" status="U" statusTime="24-04-2023 04:02:33" substatus="0" appInErr="1" descOnErr="0" blockDate="0" restartType="M" restartCount="0" restartMax="1" restartDelay="00:00:00" restartLabel="0" timeBegin="1682214471" timeEnd="1682214471" ipid="0" mepType="E">
          <Script><![CDATA[#/exploit/scripts/vtom/vtom_start_job.ksh]]></Script>
          <Parameters>
            <Parameter><![CDATA[/exploit/hra/scripts/hraccess_miquado_sql1.ksh ENV $(date +%Y-%m-%d)]]></Parameter>
          </Parameters>
          <ExpectedResources>
            <ExpectedResource resource="RH_RW_PD_hra1" operator="!" wait="1" startAfter="0" free="1">
              <Value><![CDATA[1]]></Value>
            </ExpectedResource>
          </ExpectedResources>
          <Node objectType="job" x="20" y="10" z="0"/>
        </Job>
      </Jobs>
      <Graph name="A_MIQUADO_ENV"/>
      <Node objectType="app" x="3210" y="1250" z="0"/>
    </Application>
```

Comment: `awk` is not really well suited to processing XML. Use a tool like `xmlstarlet`.

Comment: please update the question with a reduced set of input data, the code you've attempted, the (wrong) output generated by your code and the (correct) expected output; make sure both sets of output correspond with the provided sample

Answer (score 0):

First, I want to note that AWK is not very well suited for processing XML files of arbitrary format. However, we can try using the AWK for this task if we have a formatted XML file.

The general algorithm for such problems is the following:

- We collect information for a CSV record in a separate array, for example, `Record["<field name>"]`.
- When we meet the closing tag, we print the collected information and delete the array.

Perhaps the information on this link will be useful to you to solve this problem:
https://gawkextlib.sourceforge.net/xml/gawk-xml.html